# PHPMailer & Bootstrap 4 Alert

Tags: bootstrap-4, phpmailer

I have a contact form that, on submit, sends the info via PHPMailer and is supposed to return an alert-success or alert-danger notice and reset the form.

Issue: If I comment out the `$mail->send();` line on contact.php, the alert-success shows up and the form resets - as it's supposed to. However, if I leave `$mail->send();` alone, I get the email message, but no alert shows up and the form is not reset.

What am I doing wrong here?

**contact-form.html**

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" name="contact-form" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-user grey-text"></i>
      <label for="contact-name">Full Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="contact-name"/>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope grey-text"></i>
      <label for="contact-email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email"  name="contact-email" required="required"aria-describedby="emailHelp" data-error="Please enter your email address"/>
      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
   </div>
   <div class="messages"></div>
   <div class="text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" name="submit">Submit</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true); 

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();  // set SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mailserver.com';  // Server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP auth
    $mail->Username = 'info@domain.com'; 
    $mail->Password = 'password';  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLSd
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Web Contact'); // FROM
    $mail->addAddress('admin@domain.com', 'Admin - Domain'); // TO

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. We will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error. Please try again later!';

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $mail->Body    = "Full Name: ".$_POST['contact-name']."<br />Email Address: ".$_POST['contact-email']."<br /><br />";

    $mail->send();
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
?>
```

**contact.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        // if the validator good
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";
            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
                    // apply success/danger
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Generally when you have PHP generating stuff for a JS request, debug the PHP part by itself (use something like postman). The JS stuff often obscures problems happening on the server side.

Comment: @Synchro Noted and will do! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial guess, without looking at your logs, is that the $mailer->send() is throwing a fatal and not being caught in your try/catch. What version of PHP are you using? Also, your contact.js is not watching for errors, I would recommend having the ajax also watch for errors.

Try this if you're using > PHP 7.0

**contact.php**

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->isSMTP();  // set SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mailserver.com';  // Server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP auth
    $mail->Username = 'info@domain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLSd
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Web Contact'); // FROM
    $mail->addAddress('admin@domain.com', 'Admin - Domain'); // TO

    // message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
    $okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. We will get back to you soon!';

    // If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
    $errorMessage = 'There was an error. Please try again later!';

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true); // Set to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form Message';
    $mail->Body    = "Full Name: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact-name'])."<br />Email Address: ".htmlspecialchars($_POST['contact-email'])."<br /><br />";

    $mail->send();
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
} catch (Error $e) {
    // should log the fatal
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

**contact.js**

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        // if the validator good
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";
            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
                    // apply success/danger
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error('The ajax request failed:' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: PHP v7.1

Logs showed nothing. However, all I did was copy/paste in the error checking code, and it's working both locally and on the remote server?! I've been messing with this all day and it's been puzzling the heck out of me. Now I'm even more confused, but I'll take it.

Thanks!